# Why is there a line break when there are two cols in element-plus?

Tags: element-plus

Why is it that in element-plus, when there is one col in a row, it is displayed on the same line, but when there are two cols, it is displayed in a new line?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kcBg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZHUp.png)
one col:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64oaB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8jJN.png)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to read this [link](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/layout.html#column-offset)

use `<el-col :span="12" />` for both columns, it may work for you.